# SQL output parameter of varbinary to use as image on ASPX web form

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, image

I am trying to retrieve the logo stored into my table and display the image from the database to my aspx web page. I have output parameters in a SQL stored procedure which output the name and a varbinary data type. In the SQL table the first column is name which is NVARCHAR(100) and the second column is an image logo. using SQL SERVER for DBMS.

E.g. Client1 is name and Logo looks like this: 0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000000C8000000C80802000000223A39C9000000097048597300002E2300002E230178A53F76000000206348524D00007A25000080830000F9FF000080E9000075300000EA6000003A980000176F925FC546000012954944415478DAEC9D79741455BE80BFEA4EBA3B0B09092124806149D80504C20E0282FA044591F500E2809C0047715F8E8EC3E0E8F846F1313A7014C4055704065...

Example SQL code to insert into table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.client
SELECT 'Client1', BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'F:\logo.png', Single_Blob) as img
```

Stored proc called in C# code:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ui_getClientNameLogo]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ClientName NVARCHAR(100) OUTPUT,
    @Logo varbinary(max) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SET @ClientName = (SELECT Client_Name FROM dbo.client)

    SET @Logo = (SELECT Logo FROM dbo.client)

END
```

C# - Index.aspx.cs:

```
        public static void getClientInfo()
    {
        string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.sp_ui_getClientNameLogo", cn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ClientName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, ParameterDirection.Output, false,0, 10, "ClientName", DataRowVersion.Default, null));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Logo", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 1000, ParameterDirection.Output, false, 0, 10, "Logo", DataRowVersion.Default, null));
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        var dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        cn.Close();

        clientName = cmd.Parameters["@ClientName"].Value.ToString();
        **logoBinary = cmd.Parameters["@Logo"].Value. //THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK**

    }
```

How do I get the output variable of the logo and store it as an image to use on my web page??

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific. Perhaps <sql-server>?)

Comment: Using SQL SERVER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

On aspx page

```
     <img id='yourID' runat='server'/>
```

On CS page

```
      File.WriteAllBytes(yourfilename, (byte[])(cmd.Parameters["@Logo"].Value));
      byte[] logoBinary = (byte[])(cmd.Parameters["@Logo"].Value);
      string base64string= Convert.ToBase64String(logoBinary, 0, logoBinary.Length);
      yourID.Src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64String;
```

Comment: Where do i put this? and what is 'yourfilename' ?

Comment: Lets say you want to save your image on C drive then "C:\\Folder\\yourfilename.jpg" if your image is jpg.

Comment: Sorry i dont want to save my image anywhere. I have stored the image in the database in the table. I want to retrieve the image from the database and show on my ASPX web page? The logo has already been imported into the sql table from its location.

Comment: I havent got any code yet as i dont know how to get it from the database to the C# end. Please see above question -  I have made a comment where i am stuck
    **logoBinary = cmd.Parameters["@Logo"].Value. //THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK**

Comment: What i meant to say is: what is the html element you are using to show your image

Comment: <div class="media-img">
                                                <img src="./assets/img/users/u1.jpg" />
     </div>

But i want to change this image to be the one from the database. Not the one directing in this folder

Comment: byte[] logoBinary = (byte[])(cmd.Parameters["@Logo"].Value);

Comment: byte[] logoBinary = (byte[])(cmd.Parameters["@Logo"].Value);string base64string= Convert.ToBase64String()

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Check in the comments, he wants to show the image inside an img html element. And if you want to show a byte array into html img, first it has to be converted to base64 string.

Comment: @Atk  I get the error img does not exist in current context. I want to apply this source for a specific ID rather than for every image tag.

Comment: Give you img tag ID and attribute runat='server'  <img id='img' runat='server' src="./assets/img/users/u1.jpg" /> </div>